# Best way to add a Tab Bar in Table View (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I have a view controller with a Table View. I'm trying to decide the best way to add a tab bar. Do I need a tab bar controller? Should I do it in Storyboard or programmatically? I seem to be having more problems with Storyboards.

The tab bar needs to be simple with two buttons. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tab bar or tool bar?

Comment: Tab Bar, sorry I'll update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just put a tab bar on bottom and the table view on top.  These would be inside a view controller.  I'd use interface builder.  Just my opinion.

You would want to adjust your constraints appropriately.

Comment: When I try this, the tab bar doesn't stay fixed to the bottom of the screen. It either floats to the top where the navigation controller ends when the table view is empty or only stays at the bottom of the table view when it's not empty and not in it's fixed spot.

Comment: It's  probably the constraints (or lack thereof)

Comment: Thanks for accepting- hope it worked for you.  Sometimes constraints are tricky but I've really grown to like them (and InterfaceBuilder) a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Its best to embed a UIViewController in a UITabBarController. You can then control the tab bar from the UIViewController.